# Nav-tab responsive behaviour in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using nav-tabs. I want nav-tabs to be responsive so that my application will work fine in ipad view. What should i do for that.

This is my normal view
[image]

This is my ipad view
[image]

I want nav- tabs to be responsive. Is it possible? How can i do that?

Comment: do u have it in jsfiddle?

Comment: No i dont have it there

Comment: then its hard to chk and fix. until we dont see your code.

Comment: prince sodhi Hey this is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/Pinkudi/tya09jz6/

Comment: link opens but doesn't work properly.

Comment: ya tabs should be horizontal

Comment: but tabs in jsfiddle doesn't look like tabs are in image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148064/discussion-between-ashworx-and-prince-sodhi).